# Pegar o registro anterior de uma data

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou precisando fazer uma consulta, onde preciso pegar o penúltimo registro, ou seja, o registro anterior e a data também.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
prt_partner.razao_social,
prt_partner.end_cidade,
prt_partner.end_estado,
prt_partner_status.nome,
 (SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status
      WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status) AS ultima_data,

(SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
    WHERE _data_registro NOT IN (SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
    WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status)) AS data_anterior


from prt_partner
JOIN prt_partner_status ON (prt_partner.id_status = prt_partner_status.id_status)


WHERE prt_partner._ativo = 1;
```

Venho tentando fazer o select da forma acima, só que o "data_anterior" me retorna errado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDITANDO O POST**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    prt_partner.id_partner as id_parceiro,
    prt_partner.razao_social as nome_empresa,
    prt_partner.end_cidade as cidade,
    prt_partner.end_estado as estado,
    prt_partner_status.nome as status_atual,
    prt_partner_historic_status.dias_entre_status as dias_entre_status,

(SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status
          WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status) AS ultima_data,

(SELECT _data_registro FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
          WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status ORDER BY id_historic_status DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS data_anterior

FROM prt_partner

JOIN prt_partner_status ON (prt_partner.id_status = prt_partner_status.id_status)

JOIN prt_partner_historic_status ON (prt_partner.id_partner = prt_partner_historic_status.id_partner)

WHERE prt_partner._ativo = 1 ORDER BY id_parceiro;
```

O select a cima me da o seguinte retorno
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

### Solução para SQL Server

Utilizei o [`WITH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) para criar uma tabela de apoio com uma nova coluna gerada pelo [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx).
Na pesquisa, busquei o registro imediatamente anterior ao máximo de registros existente na tabela auxiliar.

Veja se te atende o seguinte código:

```
WITH TBL_DATAANTERIOR (_data_registro, numeracao)
AS
(
    SELECT _data_registro, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _data_registro) numeracao FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
    WHERE _data_registro NOT IN 
            (SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
             WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
prt_partner.razao_social,
prt_partner.end_cidade,
prt_partner.end_estado,
prt_partner_status.nome,
 (SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status
      WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status) AS ultima_data,

(SELECT _data_registro FROM TBL_DATAANTERIOR
 WHERE numeracao = (select MAX(numeracao)-1 from TBL_DATAANTERIOR) AS data_anterior

from prt_partner
JOIN prt_partner_status ON (prt_partner.id_status = prt_partner_status.id_status)
WHERE prt_partner._ativo = 1;
```

*Obs: Montei a query diretamente aqui, sem validar no `SQLServer`.*

### Solução para MySQL

*Com base na atualização da pergunta*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    prt_partner.id_partner as id_parceiro,
    prt_partner.razao_social as nome_empresa,
    prt_partner.end_cidade as cidade,
    prt_partner.end_estado as estado,
    prt_partner_status.nome as status_atual,
    prt_partner_historic_status.dias_entre_status as dias_entre_status,

    (SELECT MAX(_data_registro) FROM prt_partner_historic_status
     WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status) AS ultima_data,

    (SELECT _data_registro FROM
     (SELECT _data_registro, id_historic_status FROM prt_partner_historic_status 
      WHERE prt_partner_historic_status.id_status = prt_partner.id_status
      ORDER BY id_historic_status DESC LIMIT 2) TEMP
     ORDER BY id_historic_status ASC LIMIT 1) AS data_anterior

FROM prt_partner
JOIN prt_partner_status ON (prt_partner.id_status = prt_partner_status.id_status)
JOIN prt_partner_historic_status ON (prt_partner.id_partner = prt_partner_historic_status.id_partner)
WHERE prt_partner._ativo = 1 ORDER BY id_parceiro;
```

Comment: Esse with usa no começo mesmo?? aqui acusou como erro

Comment: Você está utilizando qual SGDB?

Comment: estou utilizando o mysql

Comment: Faltou esta informação na sua pergunta porque o WITH não é suportado no mySQL. Vou incluir na resposta uma solução para mySQL assim que possível.

Comment: Agradeço muito cara

Comment: @gabrielfalieri pensando numa solução paliativa pro `MySQL`, acho que no lugar do `WITH`, você poderia criar uma **view**, e no lugar do `row_number`, utilizar o `@rank:=@rank+1`.

Comment: É que esse select vai se tornar uma view, a view pode chamar outra view?

Comment: Com certeza. No final do processo, você terá duas views.

Comment: To sem ideia de como fazer isso... com o select simples, ao invés da view não daria certo?

Comment: Como você irá criar uma view deste select, então não poderá ter dois selects no mesmo batch. O que iria fazer é separar pra uma view a primeira parte (id_status, data_registro e _numeração da linha_) e a partir da consulta principal, buscar somente o registro MAX - 1 desta nova view.

Comment: Eu editei meu sql agora, olha como está

Comment: Com o LIMIT e o OFFSET resolveu?

Comment: Não resolveu ainda

Comment: Utilize uma variável no OFFSET para retornar o max()-1. Não posso testar agora, mas, veja esse exemplo `SELECT max(compoid)-1, t.* FROM Tabela t ORDER BY compoid DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Mesmo o id sendo não sequencial?

Tipo, tendo por exemplo, no select não uma ordem certinha?

Comment: É que a ideia do max()-1 não é referente ao id da tabela, e sim, a linha em questão. Criando uma nova coluna com o numero da linha, poderíamos pegar a penúltima linha com o offset. Dá pra tentar com o id_status < que o max(id_status) também.

Comment: Olá @gabrielfalieri, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.